# Tires friction and car force

Tags: forces, mass, acceleration

A car of mass $m$ is pushing head-on against a truck mass $2m$ from rest. The truck is pushing back. The tires are spinning on both. Will either move?

Since both have equal tires and the tires are both spinning, they have equal acceleration due to friction. The larger one has more mass so more force, but its mass also makes it harder for its tires to move it. $a = f/m$. So would the larger one move the small one or would they remain stationary?

Comment: Both have equal tires, so the **friction coefficient** $\mu_k$ is the same (it depends on the rubber, roughness, surface etc.) But the friction force itself does not depend only on the material, but also on the *normal force* $n$, which depends on the load / weight: $$f_k=\mu_k n$$ So the forces from the spinning wheels are not equal.

Comment: The forces are not equal but since a = f/m and m increases linearly with f, a is equal.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Yes, surely. Just by the fact that they move together (they are end-to-end) we know that all motion parameters, such as speed acceleration etc. are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the car and the truck are pushing on each other and will move together, it's best to think about the car and truck as one single object (the "car-truck system"), which accelerates in response to external forces. Then the *net external force* on the car-truck system is equal to the mass of the system times the acceleration of the system.

In the following analysis, I'm assuming that there is no mechanism to transfer vertical force between the car and the truck (in other words, they're not fastened together, they're just touching), so that the normal force acts separately on the car and the truck.

In this case, the only external forces are:

- The weight of the car $mg$,
- The weight of the truck $2mg$,
- The normal force exerted by the ground on the car $N_c$,
- The normal force exerted by the ground on the truck $N_t$,
- The kinetic friction exerted by the ground on the car's tires $f_c=\mu N_c$,
- The kinetic friction exerted by the ground on the truck's tires $f_t=\mu N_t$.

The weights are obviously directed downward, and the normal forces are directed upward. Since the system is known not to fly up in the air or disappear into the ground, we must have that $N_c=mg$ and $N_t=2mg$. Since the cars have equal tires, the coefficient of friction $\mu$ is the same in both cases. The kinetic friction on the car $f_c$ is directed toward the truck, and the kinetic friction on the truck $f_t$ is directed toward the car, so those two are opposing. The contact force between the car and the truck is an internal force and can be ignored because the car and the truck move together (so the contact forces always cancel out in the net force calculation).

Since the vertical forces and contact forces all cancel out, the net force on the system is simply

$$\sum F=f_t-f_c=\mu N_t- \mu N_c = 2\mu mg-\mu mg=\mu mg$$

and is directed such that the truck will move forward and the car will move backward. The acceleration of the system can be derived from Newton's Second Law:

$$\sum F=(m+2m)a\implies a=\frac{\mu mg}{3m}=\frac{1}{3}\mu g$$

So the system will accelerate.